# git server ip changed. xcode not loading branches

Tags: xcode, git, path, repository

Hi my git server ip address has changed. How can I point my current xcode project to the correct repository.

```
old       ssh://root@115.123.xxx.x
new       ssh://root@115.124.xxx.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the remote server address in your .git/config file.

Comment: Yeah that changed the remote server ip. When I look at Organizer it still shows Origin ssh://115.123.xxx.x which is the old address. Where can I find the server ips in the organizer repositories?

Comment: Might need to restart Xcode. I think it only reads the config file upon launch.

Comment: no still a red light on my old repository link. Can't or no option to change the ip for the ssh server.

Comment: Do you have multiple `[Remote]` entries declared in your .git/config?  I believe in Xcode 5, the remote IPs have moved to Source Control > "project" > Configure "project"... > Remotes

Comment: I just did a test of changing the .git/config [remote "origin"] URL, and reopening Xcode, and Xcode showed the new URL in the menu I mentioned above.

Comment: Yep. Able to push and pull to the repository. Thanks.